# How to differentiate bold text from handwriting OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

[This is the example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD6BW.png)

I have this PNG, and I am attempting to remove the bold text, but leave the handwriting. I have attempted using:

```
kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
test = cv2.erode(result, kernel)
```

But this only appears to change the thickness of the lines, not remove them.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: If you make you kernel size bigger or run erode repeatedly, it will remove the writing eventually. The thin lines will be the first to go, though. Maybe try to remove the thin lines first, then subtract that image from the starting image to retain only the bold sections.

Comment: no simple way. you need to locate and positively classify each piece of text. then you can properly deal with it.